# FileExists in Universal windows App.

Tags: win-universal-app, c++-cx, windows-10-mobile

I am developing an Universal Windows App for Windows devices.
I am developing the app in C++/CX.

In the App I want to check if a file exits on the device or not and call should be blocking call.
So I wrote a function as shown below.

```
FileExist(String^ myFolder, String ^myFile)
{
    // Get the folder object that corresponds to myFolder
    // this absolute path in the file system.
    try{
    create_task(StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync(myFolder)).then([=]                      (StorageFolder^ folder){

           create_task(folder->GetFileAsync(name)).then([=](StorageFile^ myfile){
           return true;
            });
           return false;
    });
    }
    catch (Exception^ e)
    {
            return false;
    }
}
```

But the GetFolderFromPathAsync and GetFileAsync calls are asynchronous calls and my function should be blocking so I put a wait for each of these lambda. But I am getting following error.

“An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.”

So someone please tell me how to make a blocking call for file presence for Universal Windows App.

Comment: What requires this to be in a blocking call?

Answer (score 1):

If your method runs on the UI thread - you can't make it blocking because it's using async APIs and that would prevent the async calls from returning results, causing a deadlock. You can use the blocking get() method to wait for and get a task's result if running "in a task-based continuation.".

"In a Windows Store app, do not call **wait** in code that runs on the STA. Otherwise, the runtime throws concurrency::invalid_operation because this method blocks the current thread and can cause the app to become unresponsive. However, you can call the concurrency::task::get method to receive the result of the antecedent task in a task-based continuation."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh749955.aspx